# Jasperserver - http-nio-... - Connection timed out when should service to the web site

Tags: jasperserver

We migrated the server where the Jasperserver is installed (lift and shift). IP and name of the server is the same.
We migrated oracle database and active directory servers as well. IP and name changed.
Because of that I made changes in the two files:

...\Tomcat8\webapps\jasperserver-pro\META-INF\context.xml
...\Tomcat8\webapps\jasperserver-pro\WEB-INF\applicationContext-externalAuth-CAS.xml

In addition I changed server settings (after logged in on superuser), add db and ad settings to the hosts file and tnsnames.ora.
And when I login to superuser and run reports everything works fine. I can run reports, adhoc reports. Generally any problems.
But when I run web site (stored in IIS) on the different server, I get the web page, but instead of see input controls for reports, I can see Internal Server Error (stdout, jaspersoft and iis logs you can find below).
I suppose it is something related to the CAS, but I'm not sure and I cannot find any other setting that I missed.
I will be appreciate for your help community.

1. tomcat8_env-stdout.log and jaspersoft.log

```
ERROR CommonUtils,http-nio-8450-exec-1:406 - Connection timed out: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
...
ERROR SystemErrorController,http-nio-8450-exec-1:86 - Internal server error
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:407)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:45)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticateNow(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:140)
    at org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.cas.JSCasProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(JSCasProcessingFilter.java:60)
...
```

2. IIS logs

#Date: 2023-07-16 16:25:29
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2023-07-16 16:25:29 10.18.66.24 GET /jasperserver-pro/flow.html _flowId=viewReportFlow&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2FReports%2FConnection_Register&reportUnit=%2FReports%2FConnection_Register%2FMOSL_MDS_DISCH&standAlone=true&X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=ed87c911-d5ad-4b53-9e28-ee9d96ec7ca6&SERVER-STATUS=302 443 - 10.20.0.53 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:109.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/114.0 https://www.xxx.yy/ 302 0 0 93
2023-07-16 16:25:51 10.18.66.24 GET /jasperserver-pro/j_spring_security_check;jsessionid=764CE4FCDFF8F5AD916D3BA64A90E6D3 ticket=SsQUvKkyb78a9GAX%2beY7pYZuT%2bgKmwspiXJd%2fNqvSA4%3d&X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=5620bf1e-12ea-4b89-9166-265add324737&SERVER-STATUS=500 443 - 10.20.0.53 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:109.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/114.0 https://www.xxx.yy/ 500 0 0 22018
2023-07-16 16:25:51 10.18.66.24 GET /jasperserver-pro/JavaScriptServlet X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=0b3c22fd-fe8e-4e0f-b03e-6bac3dd01a3e&SERVER-STATUS=200 443 - 10.20.0.53 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:109.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/114.0 https://reports.www.xxx.yy/jasperserver-pro/j_spring_security_check;jsessionid=764CE4FCDFF8F5AD916D3BA64A90E6D3?ticket=SsQUvKkyb78a9GAX%2beY7pYZuT%2bgKmwspiXJd%2fNqvSA4%3d 200 0 0 15
2023-07-16 16:25:51 10.18.66.24 POST /jasperserver-pro/JavaScriptServlet X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=00420f8b-2f46-4598-9b54-2895a99faafe&SERVER-STATUS=200 443 - 10.20.0.53 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:109.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/114.0 https://reports.www.xxx.yy/jasperserver-pro/j_spring_security_check;jsessionid=764CE4FCDFF8F5AD916D3BA64A90E6D3?ticket=SsQUvKkyb78a9GAX%2beY7pYZuT%2bgKmwspiXJd%2fNqvSA4%3d 200 0 0 0
2023-07-16 16:25:52 10.18.66.24 GET /jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/settings/dateTimeSettings X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=515b49de-d13a-4d7a-b977-cb81cf1a2e86&SERVER-STATUS=200 443 - 10.20.0.53 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:109.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/114.0 https://reports.www.xxx.yy/jasperserver-pro/j_spring_security_check;jsessionid=764CE4FCDFF8F5AD916D3BA64A90E6D3?ticket=SsQUvKkyb78a9GAX%2beY7pYZuT%2bgKmwspiXJd%2fNqvSA4%3d 200 0 0 0

check logs, check settings - result: report should be provided

Comment: SOLVED: the server where Jasperserver is installed has to have open the correct port to the web server where IIS/site is installed.